# Joining on Thread causes NetworkOnMainThreadException exception

Tags: android, service

I'm working on a service and I had the following code in `onStartCommand`:

```
try {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Networker.get("http://google.com/");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.run();
    t.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even though the networking code is running in another thread, my service still crashed with the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. The equivalent `AsyncTask` code does not cause this error. Is it because of the join?

I was doing this because I only need my service to run a single request and then quit, so I wanted to use the code above and return START_NON_STICKY to make the service close quickly again. Am I supposed to be doing something else instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `start()` and not `run()` on the thread to start the thread.

`run()` will just run your `Runnable` in the current thread.